# Material ui radio button selects the previous button value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have added radio button group to may reactjs app. here the problem is when i try to log the value i get the value of previous radio button instead of getting current button value.
eg. Suppose When i click on go from `all` to `awaited` then this logs `all`.
I don't know what is causing this issue.

> my Code

```
 const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = React.useState("all");

function handleChangeRadio(event) {

    const value = event.target.value;
    setRadioValue(value);
    console.log(radioValue);             <---- Here When i try to log the value. it shows the value of previous button.

  }


<RadioGroup
              className={classes.radioGroup}
              aria-label="status"
              name="status"
              value={radioValue}
              onChange={handleChangeRadio}
              row
            >
              <FormControlLabel
                checked={radioValue === "all"}
                value="all"
                control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                label="All"
                labelPlacement="end"
                className={classes.radioLabel}
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                checked={radioValue === "approved"}
                value="approved"
                control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                label="Approved"
                labelPlacement="end"
                className={classes.radioLabel}
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                checked={radioValue === "awaited"}
                value="awaited"
                control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                label="Awaited"
                labelPlacement="end"
                className={classes.radioLabel}
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                checked={radioValue === "on_hold"}
                value="on_hold"
                control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                label="On Hold"
                labelPlacement="end"
                className={classes.radioLabel}
              />
            </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know that:

`setState` actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains. This is explained in the documentation of setState.

but Why?
`setState` alters the state and causes rerendering. This can be an expensive operation and making it synchronous might leave the browser unresponsive

Thus the setState calls are asynchronous as well as batched for better UI experience and performance.

What if I need to do something after `setState`?

if you had a `React Class Component` you can do what you need inside `setState callback` like this:

```
this.setState(newState, function(){
   // Do what it needs to be done after updating newState here
});
```

and if you had a `React Functional Component` you need to listen for `state change` with `useEffect` hook and do what you need in `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Do what it needs to be done after updating state here
}, [radioValue])
```

Answer (score 3):

The state update using the updater provided by useState hook is asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect.

Try to read the value with `useEffect()` hook instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(radioValue)
}, [radioValue])
```

Comment: is there any solutions for this ?